# Storing multiple values in Session under one key - possible list of Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm trying to figure out a way to store multiple values in my Session variable. This is how I do it currently:

```
Session[ID] = Products;
Session["type"] = type;
Session["shipping"] = shipping;
Session["condition"] = condition;
Session["minprice"] = minprice;
Session["maxprice"] = maxprice;
```

The way I imagine it to be is that I store all these under the same KEY which is ID in my case ( an generated GUID value - 02df0-2k4l9 for example), so that I could access all of these values like following:

```
Session[ID]["type"];
Session[ID]["condition"];
```

And so on... Is there a way to do this, and if yes, what's the best possible way?

Comment: you can do this in other way. Make a class "Products". have all the properties "type", "shipping". In Session variable assign the object.

Comment: @viveknuna quite a good idea, let's hear what others have to say as well =)

Comment: @viveknuna is it possible that I make list of anonymous objects instead of creating a class?

Comment: But on the other side, it makes your application slower, when We use complex type in Session variable

Comment: @viveknuna exactly, maybe using a list of annonymous objects ?

Comment: @viveknuna sry I ment an anonymous object with value of these variables..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a `class MYCLASS` with properties as "`type`", "`shipping`"... etc.. and store the instance of that class in session?

When you want to use it, simply Extract the instance from `Session` Variable , typecast it into `MYCLASS` and use it.

will that solve your problem ?

Cheers

Comment: good idea, we were just discussing it. What about making a list of anonymous objects instead of creating a class?

Comment: @RohitKhanna Thaks for copying my idea :P

Comment: Guys what about simply creating a dynamic anonymous object? :D Like this:   var Settings = new { _products = Products , _type= type, _shipping = shipping }; Session[ID] = settings;

Answer (score 2):

You can investigate what others have answered, including defining a specific class if that fits your requirements. In addition to what has been answered, you can use a dictionary that uses string as a key, and an object as a value. Then you can store in it your values, and read from it as the following.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

dictionary["type"] = type;
dictionary["shipping"] = shipping;
dictionary["condition"] = condition;
dictionary["minprice"] = minprice;
dictionary["maxprice"] = maxprice;

Session [ID] = dictionary;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of objects from your values lets assume you call it `Product` which is a class of your objects:

```
List<Product> list = new List<Product>();
//how to store them
Session["SessionName"] = list;
//how to receive the list again 
var list = (List<Product>)Session["SessionName"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like create a class which hold all the values

```
    public class ProductData
    {
        public Product objProduct { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string shipping { get; set; }
        public string condition { get; set; }
        public decimal minprice { get; set; }
        public decimal maxprice { get; set; }
    }
```

and assign that class object to session like

```
Session[ID] = objProductsData;
```

Comment: can I just simply create an annonymous object and store it in session ?

Comment: yes you can but if you know which values will be there.. I mean if structure is fixed then use of class is good @User987